# Can't Get Docker Image

Tags: java, spring, jenkins-pipeline, testcontainers

I have 5 spring batch tests I am running on a Jenkins pipeline using testcontainers. I am getting the following error only on ONE of the tests:

```
12:51:53  17 Mar 2020;17:51:41.498 [user:] [request:] [main] INFO 
12:51:53                  o.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory - Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
12:51:53          [37m[1mℹ︎ Checking the system...[0m[0m
12:51:53          [32m✔ Docker version should be at least 1.6.0[0m
12:51:53  17 Mar 2020;17:51:41.508 [user:] [request:] [main] DEBUG
12:51:53                  c.g.d.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: f6fc0588843eb76a458bdc25cdc942fed474945aa3cfe7b635220dd1935dbfaa,<null>,true,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,{df,-P},<null>,<null>,com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.ExecCreateCmdExec@5cbe877d
12:51:53  17 Mar 2020;17:51:41.644 [user:] [request:] [tc-okhttp-stream-2116511124] DEBUG
12:51:53                  c.g.d.c.c.ExecStartResultCallback - STDOUT: Filesystem           1024-blocks    Used Available Capacity Mounted on
12:51:53  overlay              314561516  62506464 252055052  20% /
12:51:53  tmpfs                    65536         0     65536   0% /dev
12:51:53  tmpfs                  8132940         0   8132940   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
12:51:53  shm                      65536         0     65536   0% /dev/shm
12:51:53  /dev/xvdg1           314561516  62506464 252055052  20% /etc/resolv.conf
12:51:53  /dev/xvdg1           314561516  62506464 252055052  20% /etc/hostname
12:51:53  /dev/xvdg1           314561516  62506464 252055052  20% /etc/hosts
12:51:53  tmpfs                  8132940     25132   8107808   0% /run/docker.sock
12:51:53  tmpfs                  8132940         0   8132940   0% /proc/acpi
12:51:53  tmpfs                    65536         0     65536   0% /proc/kcore
12:51:53  tmpfs                    65536         0     65536   0% /proc/keys
12:51:53  tmpfs                    65536         0     65536   0% /proc/timer_list
12:51:53  tmpfs                    65536         0     65536   0% /proc/timer_stats
12:51:53  tmpfs                    65536         0     65536   0% /proc/sched_debug
12:51:53  tmpfs                  8132940         0   8132940   0% /proc/scsi
12:51:53  tmpfs                  8132940         0   8132940   0% /sys/firmware
12:51:53          [32m✔ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space[0m
12:51:53  17 Mar 2020;17:51:41.690 [user:] [request:] [main] DEBUG
12:51:53                  c.g.d.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: ListImagesCmdImpl[imageNameFilter=<null>,showAll=false,filters=com.github.dockerjava.core.util.FiltersBuilder@0,execution=com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.ListImagesCmdExec@3ecd267f]
12:51:53  [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.915 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.oranj.snowflake.account.VendorAccountTransactionSnowflakeConfigurationTest
12:51:53  [ERROR] com.oranj.snowflake.account.VendorAccountTransactionSnowflakeConfigurationTest  Time elapsed: 1.914 s  <<< ERROR!
12:51:53  org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
12:51:53  Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageNameFuture=java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@37ddb69a[Completed normally], imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy(), dockerClient=LazyDockerClient.INSTANCE)
12:51:53  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key ImageData(createdAt=1970-01-18T18:51:50.819Z)
12:51:53
```

It seems like when the JVM terminates it is not properly cleaning up after itself. Thus, when it starts up again it is trying to start the container but it sees a duplicate container there already. This is when I rerun the test multiple times. I can't reproduce this on my local mac os.

Environment:

- List item
- Server Version: 19.03.1
- API Version: 1.40
- Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
- Total Memory: 15884 MB

Comment: I have an open Github ticket with the team(https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2431) but if anyone could offer more guidance or a workaround that would be great

Comment: Can you share the batch tests? There is a chance that the failing one has different image (typo?).

Comment: All the jobs reference the same Class so if one had a typo then all of them would

Comment: I've noticed this weird creation date, `createdAt=1970-01-18` , I guess this is a bug in testcontainers where creation date is sent by docker as epoch but interpreted by testcontainers as millis. This causes the `AgeBasedPullPolicy` work incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was solved in the following Github issue!

https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2431

Comment: "docker system prune -af" was the solution for me.